# linq query to DB returns model with list, when model is ok but list is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

This drives me crazy I have mode with list of two other models in it. As long as I had there iCollections it worked fine, but I had to change them to List, because I need to export the data into XML.

**Model**

```
public class PortalUser
{
    //private List<UserToTeam> UserToTeam_ = new List<UserToTeam>();
    //private List<Mandays> Mandays_ = new List<Mandays>();

    public int ID { get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Role Role { get; set; }

    //public virtual ICollection<Mandays> Mandays { get; set; }
    public List<Mandays> Mandays { get; set; } //{ return Mandays_; }
    [DisplayName("Team")]
    //public virtual ICollection<UserToTeam> UserToTeam { get; set; }
    public List<UserToTeam> UserToTeam { get; set; } //{ return UserToTeam_; }

    public PortalUser()
    {
        Mandays = Mandays ?? new List<Mandays>();
        UserToTeam = UserToTeam ?? new List<UserToTeam>();
    }
```

Then I use this to get data from the DB

```
   List<PortalUser> dbAgent = db.PortalUser.ToList();
```

End while debugging the result ends as Count = 0. While iCollection return the model within model correctly the List always returns Count = 0. In DB Users have Mandays and even team, but result is always empty.

I am sure I am missing something simple, please help. I can post more code if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if EF supports a List collection like that, however you need the virtual keyword in there so EF can create wrapped collections appropriately.

Comment: Oh God I am so blind. Thanks a lot it was the missing virtual keyword.